# typescript how to combine two objects to an array

Tags: typescript

I am newbie to typescript.

I have two objects of Student class. May be AStudent and BStudent
Now i want to have a method which returns an combined array containing if they are not null

if both are not null , array will be [AStudent ,BStudent] ;IF AStudent  is not empty and BStudent is null ,array will be [AStudent ]

how to achieve this in typescript?

Thanks

Comment: Really depends a lot on how you are getting the objects, code samples or a minimal verifiable example is preferred.

Comment: `let arr = []; if (AStudent != null) arr.push(AStuden);...` - repeat for `BStudent`,return.

Comment: I am hoping some typescript solution rather than plain if else

Comment: @Jocket - Whats wrong with a plain `if/else`? It fits your case. You can do `[AStudent, BStudent].filter(s => s != null);`

Comment: @tymeJV Can you please post the full version of this filter as answer ?i will try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add everything to an array then use `Array.filter`

```
let arr = [AStudent, BStudent].filter(s => !!s);
```

Comment: How to check if S for truthy than null so that undefiend,null are being caught?

Answer (score 1):

```
combineTwoObject(obj1 = null, obj2 = null) {
  let objArray = [];
  if(obj1 != null)
    objArray.push(obj1);
  if(obj2 != null)
    objArray.push(obj2);
  return objArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very abstract method to achive this, which would fit your case of starting with two students, but also allows you to use the function with other types, and other sizes of collection. I also took the liberty of handling `null` and `undefined`.

```
function definedObjects<T>(...obj: T[]): T[]{
  return obj.filter(s => !!s);
}

interface Student {
  name: string;
}

var studentA: Student = { name: 'Steve' };
var studentB: Student = { name: 'Jocket' };
var studentC: Student; // undefined
var studentD: Student = null;

const result = definedObjects(studentA, studentB, studentC, studentD);
```

Answer (score 0):

You lose some flexibility, but another method is to extend the Array class with one that doesn't accept `undefined`.  Something like this:

```
export class NoUndefinedArray<T> extends Array<T> {

   constructor() {
      super();
   }

   push(item: T) {
      if (item !== undefined) {
         super(push);
      }
   }

   concat(item: T | T[]) {
      const arr = [].concat(item).filter(i => i !== undefined);
      return super(arr);
   }
}
```